# How to set the path of include in EJS file

Tags: node.js, ejs

When designing the ejs code for a nodeJs demo, I want to use "<%- include XX%>" to include other ejs file. However, I want to set dynamicly which file to include. What should I do? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this code when you want to use dynamic include. 
 take your filename as variable

```
<%- include( yourvariable ) ℅>
```

for example

```
filename='header.ejs';
<%-include(filename) %>
```